Custom instrumentation in Sentry browser profiling?
I need some help in understanding the "Custom Instrumentation" feature in Sentry browser profiling. As per their documentation, "Browser Profiling" is currently on beta, and "Continuous profiling" is not yet supported.
I have tried using the method they provide. By using the integration method browserProfilingIntegration, I was able to enable profiling. However, as I expected, the profiling data is only being captured during a URL change.
I want to capture profiling data for a specific use case where the URL doesn't change. So I followed the "Custom instrumentation" approach described here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/tracing/instrumentation/custom-instrumentation/
This method is described for "Browser Tracing". Can this also be used for "Browser Profiling"? If so, does anyone has a link to the relevant documentation?
